# How to create a Asp.net Mvc3 application with TelerikExtension controls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

I have develop small Asp.net MVC3 application using Telerik rad Controls with in that i have try to get the list of data for that i have create strong type view control,it is create all the controls and i run the application it showing error like **Object Reference null Exception** 
in my database i have 10 records then why it shoeing the error please help me ...here i have post my code please refer this once.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<TelerikMvcApplication1.Models.tb1_post>" %>

      <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
        Index
      </asp:Content>

       <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

       <h2>Index</h2>

      <fieldset>
          <legend>tb1_post</legend>

                <div class="display-label">post</div>
                 <div class="display-field"><%: Model.post %></div>

               <div class="display-label">postdate</div>
                <div class="display-field"><%: String.Format("{0:g}", Model.postdate) %></div>

               <div class="display-label">username</div>
                  <div class="display-field"><%:Model.username %></div>
               </fieldset>
                  <p>

                    <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=Model.postid }) %> |
                  <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
                 </p>

                 </asp:Content>
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace and tell me which line the error is on?

Comment: Hi thank you for giving response it showing the error at <%: Model.post %> here in normal mvc i got the solution.Just i create the control in that view page (Index) adding the viewcontrol in that i have select strong typed ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is happening at the first reference to the model, therefore the Model is null.  Make sure that the MVC controller is properly instantiating the model for the view.

Comment: Hi,I have try for editing data it is working in same control but here i have pass the id values manually.